# Pass the final/draft option to the document from the command line

Tags: draft, documentclass, command-line

I have a document that starts with

```
\documentclass[aps, pra, draft]{revtex4}
```

Once in while I want to change draft for final but without modifying the file.

How can I effectively change draft to final during compilation?
Is there a way to do it from the command line, (e.g. `pdflatex`)?

Of course I could do it with `sed` find and replace but that will create new auxiliary files, I am wondering if there is a more idiomatic way.

Comment: Suppose you have `main.tex` containing `\documentclass[aps, pra]{revtex4}`, then you can use `pdflatex "\makeatletter\def\@classoptionslist{draft}\makeatother\input{article-test}"` (here `"` is OS/shell dependent) to pass option `draft` to class `revtex4`.

Answer (score 3):

muzimuzhi's suggestion in the comments did not work for me, but something similar does:

```
xelatex '\PassOptionsToClass{draft}{revtex4}\input{my_texfile_name}'
```

Comment: I tried both solutions and found that they both worked except that @muzimuzhi Z's solution will remove any options that you specify in the 'tex' file, e.g. 'aps' and 'pra'. On the other hand it is a little inconvenient that your solution requires the specification of the documentclass.